# Output matches expected output. Yet submission is not being accepted

Tags: python, python-3.x

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/designer-door-mat/problem

Below is my submission:

```
n = input().split(' ')
rows, columns = int(n[0]), int(n[1])
if(rows % 2 == 1 and columns == 3*rows):
   printale = ''
   j = 1
   k = rows - 7
   for i in range(int(rows/2), -1, -1):
       printale = '---'*i + '.|.'*j + '---'*i
       if(i == 0):
           print('-'*int(j+k/2) + 'Welcome' + '-'*int(j+k/2))
           j -= 2
       else:
           print(printale)
           j += 2
   for l in range(1, int(rows/2)+1):
       printale = '---'*l + '.|.'*j + '---'*l
       print(printale)
       j -= 2
```

Is there anything wrong with the code?

Comment: The examples use `WELCOME`, while your code has `Welcome`.

Comment: Your code allows for N = 1 or N = 3, and N > 100, which is outside of the given constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is.  The "WELCOME" in the problem statement is all-caps.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have been so obsessed with getting the pattern right, didn't realize that the statement was expected to be in uppercase. Thank you m(_ _)m